# 404 status code returned by silex is not redirected by .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, silex

my .htaccess works fine when I type manually a wrong url it redirects to my custom 404 page. Here is my .htaccess (this the hole content (no other redirects)):

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 http://codeexample.local/404.shtml
```

Now in my Silex based application I return a 404 status code if the client tries to edit a non existent client. Even though the status code is indeed 404 as i can see with curl -v. But for some reason it is not redirected to 404 error page.

Here is how I access the url:

```
http://codeexample.local/index.php/2/edit
```

Here is my index.php edit route section:

```
$app->match('/{id}/edit', function (Request $request, $id) use ($app) {
    try {
        $clientController = new ClientController($request, $id);
        return $clientController->editAction($app);
    }
    catch(\Exception $e){
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
})
->assert('id', '\d+')
->method('GET|POST');
```

in my editAction method I am checking if the client exists in the database otherwhise I am returning a response like this:

```
$response = new Response(
        '',
        Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND,
        array('content-type' => 'text/html')
        );
$response->prepare($request);
$response->send();

return $response;
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your expectations are a bit off here, possibly. The web server will handle requests for addresses it has no knowledge of with a 404 response, and you can also provide it with some HTML to send along with the 404 response. But it's the 404 response that is really the important bit.

Telling the web server that 404.shtml is the mark-up to send back to the browser is not like a *redirect* to that page, it simply uses the contents of that file for the HTML to send back with the 404 response.

Silex knows nothing about that, as the web server's 404-handling is long since fallen out of the picture by the time Silex gets anywhere near the request. When there's a 404 condition at the Silex end of things you need to do two things: return a 404 code in the response (you're doing that now), and you can optionally send some content back too (like the markup in that 404.shtml file). If you want to have the same 404 mark-up as the 404.shtml that the web server uses... read that file and return it as the content with your 404 response.

You could try to go a different route and rejig your web server 404 to return the result of a Silex-routed URL, and then use that same route internally for the content of 404s from Silex too, but I think it's the wrong approach for the web server to be bugging PHP/Silex for a response to a request which has already been identified as invalid.

What you really really do *not* want to do is redirect from Silex to a doc containing mark-up for a 404. What that will do is tell the user agent that the URL it tried was incorrect, and it should try *another one* (as provided by the redirect header), which will then return a 404 message to the human in the mark-up, but will be returning 200-OK to the user agent. So in effect when a user agent browses to /someBadPage.html you'd be telling them the correct document for that URL is /404.html. Not that /someBadPage.html does not exist.

Comment: Cheers for the down vote with no explanation. That really helps the community. Nice work. Well done *you*.

Answer (score 0):

you should redirect to the error page.

```
$app->redirect( '/404.shtml' );
```

In your code you are creating a new Response with a statuscode. This is too late for the apacheserver to react. 
And other idea is to call the function which creates the errorpage, but i would say don't do that to keep the code clean.

Comment: You don't want to redirect to a 404 page, you want to 404 the page they browsed to. The object of the exercise is not to simply return a view saying "we don't have that page", you want to tell the *browser* (and more importantly search engines) that the *URL that was requested* is not available. Not a response which says "I think you meant this page", which is what a redirect means.